# Did refactoring to put code in another function affect timing in my Javascript Tic-Tac-Toe here?

Tags: javascript, scope, return, refactoring, tic-tac-toe

For a TicTacToe game below, everything works well but in the same block of code, I use these lines twice:

```
      if (playerhasWon()) {
        declareWinner()
        return
      } 
      
      if (emptySpaceRemains() == false) {
        declareTie()
        return
      }
```

I wanted to refactor and call those two if statements, `function hasGameEnded()`.

However, if use `hasGameEnded()`, a weird thing happens with my code.

After the player has won the game, the computer does not respect the `return` that should stop the game.

Instead, it sends the alert in `declareWinner()` but then also runs the next function `swapTurns()` and lets the AI plays its move.

If I leave in the 2 if statements, it works fine. Why is this?

Has putting `playerhasWon()` function in another block affected the firing my my `return`? Does it delay firing so that the computer isn't aware the game is won and still plays its piece?

```js
var ONE_CLASS
var TWO_CLASS

const btn = document.querySelector('#PlayerOneSymbol');

btn.onclick = function() {
  const XOs = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="choice"]');
  for (const XO of XOs) {
    if (XO.checked) {
      ONE_CLASS = XO.value
      TWO_CLASS = XO.value == 'X' ? 'O' : 'X'
      break;
    }
  }
  alert("First Move Belongs to " + ONE_CLASS + ". Select Player Two.");
};

var playerTwoIdentity

const btn2 = document.querySelector('#PlayerTwoChoice');
btn2.onclick = function() {
  const Opponents = document.querySelectorAll('input[name="choice2"]');
  for (const Opponent of Opponents) {
    if (Opponent.checked) {
      playerTwoIdentity = Opponent.value
      break;
    }
  }
  alert("Your Opponent is " + playerTwoIdentity + ". Start New Game.")
};

let playerOneTurn

function swapTurns() {
  playerOneTurn = !playerOneTurn
};

const winningTrios = [
  [0, 1, 2],
  [3, 4, 5],
  [6, 7, 8],
  [0, 3, 6],
  [1, 4, 7],
  [2, 5, 8],
  [0, 4, 8],
  [6, 4, 2]
]

restartBtn.addEventListener('click', startGame);

function startGame() {
  if (ONE_CLASS == undefined || playerTwoIdentity == undefined) {
    return alert("Make sure players are defined")
  }
  console.log("player 1 = " + ONE_CLASS + ", player 2 = " + playerTwoIdentity)
  drawBoard();
  playerOneTurn = true;
}

const arrayfromBoxes = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('box'));
const stylingOfBoxes = document.querySelectorAll('.box');

function drawBoard() {
  console.log(stylingOfBoxes)
  for (let i = 0; i < stylingOfBoxes.length; i++) {
    stylingOfBoxes[i].addEventListener('click', boxmarked, {
      once: true
    });
  }
  stylingOfBoxes.forEach(gridBox => {
    gridBox.classList.remove(ONE_CLASS)
    gridBox.classList.remove(TWO_CLASS)
    gridBox.classList.remove('winner')
    gridBox.innerHTML = ""
  })
}

function boxmarked(e) {
  const index = arrayfromBoxes.indexOf(e.target)
  // how to consolidate? maybe I just let ONE_CLASS mark and then if the AI or player
  // or do it even earlier and link it with playerTurn? 
  if (playerOneTurn) {
    arrayfromBoxes[index].classList.add(ONE_CLASS)
    e.target.innerHTML = ONE_CLASS
  } else {
    arrayfromBoxes[index].classList.add(TWO_CLASS)
    e.target.innerHTML = TWO_CLASS
  }

  // if (playerhasWon()) {
  //   declareWinner()
  //   return
  // } 

  // if (emptySpaceRemains() == false) {
  //   declareTie()
  //   return
  // }
  hasGameEnded()
  swapTurns()

  // eliminate repetition - 
  if (playerTwoIdentity === "Dumb AI") {
    var dumbAIArray = arrayfromBoxes.reduce((dumbAIArray, box, idx) => {
      if (box.innerHTML === "") {
        dumbAIArray.push(idx);
      }
      return dumbAIArray;
    }, []);
    let dumbAIpicked = dumbAIArray[Math.floor(dumbAIArray.length * (Math.random()))]
    arrayfromBoxes[dumbAIpicked].classList.add(TWO_CLASS)
    arrayfromBoxes[dumbAIpicked].innerHTML = TWO_CLASS

    // why does Timeoutfunction prevent opponent sequence?
    // setTimeout(() => {arrayfromBoxes[dumbAIpicked].classList.add(TWO_CLASS)}, 500);
    // setTimeout(() => {arrayfromBoxes[dumbAIpicked].innerHTML = TWO_CLASS}, 500);

    // if (playerhasWon()) {
    //   declareWinner()
    //   return
    // } 

    // if (emptySpaceRemains() == false) {
    //   declareTie()
    //   return
    // }

    hasGameEnded()
    swapTurns()
  } else {
    console.log("Human")
  }
}

function hasGameEnded() {
  // fix declareWinner() appears before the added classes bc alert happens quicker than redraw
  // I also cannot pull these out because then the opponent move fires and shows
  // could have something to do with timing of in-block code
  if (playerhasWon()) {
    declareWinner()
    return
  }

  if (emptySpaceRemains() == false) {
    declareTie()
    return
  }
}

function checkClass() {
  if (playerOneTurn) {
    return ONE_CLASS
  } else {
    return TWO_CLASS
  };
}

function emptySpaceRemains() {
  var innerHTMLempty = (insidebox) => insidebox.innerHTML === ""
  console.log(arrayfromBoxes.some(innerHTMLempty))
  return (arrayfromBoxes.some(innerHTMLempty))
}

function declareTie() {
  setTimeout(alert("TIE GAME"), 1000)
}

function playerhasWon() {
  var indexOfSelected = arrayfromBoxes.reduce((indexOfSelected, box, idx) => {
    if (box.classList[1] === checkClass()) {
      indexOfSelected.push(idx);
    }
    return indexOfSelected;
  }, []);

  const winningThreeIndexes = winningTrios
    .map(trio => trio.filter(i => indexOfSelected.includes(i)))
    .filter(i => i.length === 3);

  console.log(winningThreeIndexes)
  console.log(winningThreeIndexes.length)

  if (winningThreeIndexes.length === 1) {
    winningThreeIndexes[0].map((index) => {
      arrayfromBoxes[index].className += ' winner'
    })
  }

  var isThereAWinner =
    winningTrios.some(trio => {
      return trio.every(i => indexOfSelected.includes(i))
    });
  console.log({
    isThereAWinner
  });
  return isThereAWinner
}

function declareWinner() {
  setTimeout(alert(checkClass() + " WINS"), 1000);
  for (let i = 0; i < stylingOfBoxes.length; i++) {
    stylingOfBoxes[i].removeEventListener('click', boxmarked, {
      once: true
    });
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

#playtext {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 10px;
}

.buttonHolder {
  height: 60px;
  width: 100%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  background-color: purple;
}

.buttonWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.container {
  background-color: purple;
  justify-content: center;
  /* display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap; */
  width: 400px;
  height: 600px;
}

#gameboard {
  border-top: 10px;
  border-bottom: 4px;
  border-bottom-color: black;
  background-color: chartreuse;
}

.box {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 125px;
  height: 125px;
  float: left;
  width: 33.33%;
}

button:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: translateY(-2px);
}

.winner {
  background-color: black;
}

.X {
  content: 'X';
  font-size: 135px;
}

.O {
  content: 'O';
  font-size: 135px;
}

#spacer {
  height: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: purple;
  padding: 10px;
}

#playerOne {
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 110px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}

#playerTwo {
  background-color: mintcream;
  padding: 5px;
  height: 110px;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Tic Tac Toe</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1 id="playtext">Let's Play</h1>

    <div class="radioContainer">
      <div id="playerOne">
        <h3>Player One</h3>
        <form>
          <input type="radio" name="choice" value="X"> X<br>
          <input type="radio" name="choice" value="O"> O<br>
          <input type="button" id="PlayerOneSymbol" value="Confirm">
        </form>
      </div>

      <div id="playerTwo">
        <h3>Player Two</h3>
        <form>
          <input type="radio" name="choice2" value="Human"> Human<br>
          <input type="radio" name="choice2" value="Dumb AI"> Dumb AI<br>
          <input type="radio" name="choice2" value="Smart AI"> Smart AI<br>
          <input type="button" id="PlayerTwoChoice" value="Confirm">
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="buttonHolder">
      <div class="buttonWrapper">
        <button id="restartBtn">Start New Game</button>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="gameboard">
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
      <div class="box"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: return  in a function means end that function but not means end in caller. you need return some value as state to check or throw error to stop it.

Comment: ahhh, thanks, I understand part of that but not all! if "return in a function means end that function" then that could explain why function `boxmarked(e)` does not end when I take the returns out and put them in a new function `function hasGameEnded()`. I need to learn what "return value as state" means.

Answer (score 1):

return in a function means end that function but not end in caller. you need to return some value as state or throw error to stop.

for example:

```js
function hasGameEnded() {
  // fix declareWinner() appears before the added classes bc alert happens quicker than redraw
  // I also cannot pull these out because then the opponent move fires and shows
  // could have something to do with timing of in-block code
  if (playerhasWon()) {
    declareWinner()
    return true
  }

  if (emptySpaceRemains() == false) {
    declareTie()
    return true
  }

  return false
}

function boxmarked(e) {
  ...

  if (hasGameEnded()) {
    // game end by someone win or tie
    // .. do something to stop
  } else {
    swapTurns()
  }
}
```